# Extract URL from WMS in layertree in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, wms, url

I get a QGIS project with more than 60 different WMS layers. The layers are in different subgroups. Now I want to get a list of all layernames and the URL of the layer.

Therefore I tried the following code from the QGIS cheat sheet:

```
from qgis.core import QgsLayerTreeGroup, QgsLayerTreeLayer
def get_group_layers(group):
  print('- group: ' + group.name())
  for child in group.children():
     if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
    
       get_group_layers(child)
     else:
       print('  - layer: ' + child.name())

root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
for child in root.children():
   if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
      get_group_layers(child)
   elif isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
      print ('- layer: ' + child.name())
```

How can I get the URL of my single layers?
If there is a solution without PyQGIS, that would be fine too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `layer.source()` and split the source string at `url=`:

```
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    src = layer.source()
    url = src.split('url=')[1]
    print(f"{layer.name()}:   {url}")
```

[image]